# SQL ERROR - on Updating Column Value in First Table Based on Other Two Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have 3 Tables `OrderPayment`, `OrderSummaryInfo` and `OrderLossEntity`.

`OrderPayment` table has a column `OrdertypeCD`, `OrderLossEntity` table has a column `OrderType`.

There is no direct relation between all the 3 tables.

`Ordersummary` has a primary key `orderevententity`. This table is the master table for both the tables (`OrderPayment` and `OrderLossEntity`).

`OrderSummaryinfo` table has a column called `orderNumber` and `OrderPayment` table also has `OrderNumber`. This `OrderNumber` is the  primary key in `OrderPayment` table and is referring to `OrderSummaryinfo`:

```
OrderSummaryInfo.OrderNumber = OrderPayment.OrderNumber
```

`OrderSummaryinfo.orderevententity` is the primary key for `OrderLosseventEntity.id` --> where is the primary key in `OrderLosseventEntity` table referring to `OrderSummaryinfo.orderevententity`:

```
OrderSummaryinfo.orderevententity = OrderLossEntity.id
```

My requirement is `OrderTypeCD` has 3 possible values "Cash", "Gift" and "rewards".

`OrderType` column has 2 possible values - "Direct" and "Indirect".

Wherever `OrderTypeCD` has value "Rewards", I should change it to a new value "CashBack" for those orders which have `OrderType="Indirect"`.

I am trying a query but I get an error

```
UPDATE Orderpayment op 
JOIN OrderSummaryInfo osi ON op.orderNumber = osi.OrderNumber 
JOIN OrderLossEntity ole ON ole.id = osi.orderevententity 
SET op.ordertypeCd = 'CashBck'  
WHERE op.orderTypeCD = 'Rewards' 
  AND ole.OrdeType = 'Indirect';
```

I get an error

> SQL State : 42601

Please help me correct this query.

Comment: PostgreSQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS. What are you using ?

Comment: Hi  @AymDev   I'm using postgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error is the sequence of clauses. The `set` clause must immediately follow the `update` and you cannot use table alias in the `set` (see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)). So you need:

```
update OrderPayment  op 
   set OrderTypeCd = 'CashBck' ...
```

Secondly, the `from` portion must follow standard SQL format, so `update table_name set column_name join` will also give a syntax. To accomplish the necessary join you need a "sub select". Taking this and the above together along with your other stated requirements you get:

```
update OrderPayment  op 
   set OrderTypeCd = 'CashBck'  
  from (select  osi.OrderNumber 
        from OrderSummaryInfo osi
        join OrderLossEntity  ole 
          on ole.id = osi.OrderEventEntity
        where ole.OrderType = 'Indirect'
       ) jOrder
where op.OrderNumber = jOrder.OrderNumber
  and op.OrderTypeCd = 'Rewards';
```

**NOTE:** Not tested, no test data supplied.

Comment: Hi @Belayer Thanks for your Replay and answer, it s executing perfectly  , in the above query what is the  word 'jOrder'?
Thanks